# Picking a concrete type based on a configuration parameter

Tags: c++, factory

I have a code base that contains several different instances of the following pattern, the key point of which is that the concrete type of the class is decided at run time based on a string from a config file.

```
class Foo {
public:
    virtual void bar() = 0;
};

class AFoo : Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        // ...
    }

    static Foo* create() {
        return new AFoo();
    }
};

class BFoo : Foo {
public:
    void bar() {
        // ...
    }

    static Foo* create() {
        return new AFoo();
    }
};

class FooFactory {
public:
    void register(std::string typeName, std::function<unique_ptr()> ctor) {
        registeredTypes[typeName] = ctor;
    }

    Foo* create(const std::string& typeName) {
        return registeredTypes[typeName]();
    }

private:
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<Foo*()>> registeredTypes;
};

int main() {
    FooFactory factory = new FooFactory();
    factory.register("A", AFoo::Create);
    factory.register("B", BFoo::Create);

    Foo* = factory.create("A");
}
```

First of all, I'm not really sure that "Factory" is the right name for this pattern. Is there a better name for the pattern of "Select a type based on a string and instantiate that type"?

Second, I really dislike the manual registration of types, but I can't see any other way to do it given C++'s limited run time type information. Can anyone offer a better solution that automatically finds all sub-classes of Foo at compile time?

Third, my manager and I disagree on where the factory method should live. I would prefer to have it in `Foo` itself, whereas he likes the current pattern better. Neither of us has a particularly strong argument though. Is there any substantial reason to prefer one or the other?

Comment: You noticed that c++ already supports RTTI and things like `typeid()` already, did you? I don't know what you mean regarding _"C++'s limited run time type information"_.

Comment: I mean that `typeid()` allows me to get a typeid for a particular type, but it doesn't let me do more powerful things like enumerate all types that inherit from a base type, which is what I would do in a language like Java or C# in a similar situation.

Comment: C++'s compilation model **can't** let you know "all subclasses of a base class" in the general case. Each translation unit is an island

Answer (score 5):

1. Yes, Factory is the right name for this pattern.
2. No, C++ does not offer a way to enumerate types. You can perhaps reduce the necessary boilerplate with some clever macros, but I would not suggest it.
3. Your manager is right. If you put the code in `Foo`, then it would become global state, and you want to avoid that. Having an explicit `FooFactory` allows you to scope this information better.

Comment: I *explicitly* want global state though. I effectively want a global mapping from strings to types. Can you elaborate on why you think I should avoid global state?

Comment: @Jason Because then every part of the code can change the global state. Thus when your global state changes in some unexpected and undesirable way you will have a hard time figuring out which part of the code is to blame and to fix.

Answer (score 1):

For questions 1) and 2) I can't really say more than Sebastian Redl already said so well - "factory" is the right name, and while there is a way via macro-voodo-magic (e.g. the google test framework enumerates all testcases on its own) you should really consider twice before doing that.

As for question 3) I can only point to the [single-responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) - *"A class should have only one reason to change."* The responsiblity of the `Foo` classes is to do `bar()`. Holding a mapping of all potential subclasses of `Foo` and determining which subclass of `Foo` to create is a different responsibility. (Also reconsider mapping with strings. Map the string to an enum when loading, and use that enum to map to your classes - this way you don't need to sprinkle "A", "B, "C" all over the code AND reduce the risk fr bugs - you are much more likely to miss a typo in a string than in an enum.)

Comment: I'm well aware that strings are not ideal, but I don't see a way around it. The purpose of this pattern is to allow for concrete types that the library containing the base class knows nothing about, which makes defining an enum that covers all concrete types impossible. I would love to hear any alternative to strings that works across library boundaries.

Comment: Regarding SRP, that's a fair point, but given that my goal is to instantiate classes from a list that would ideally be generated at compile-time, I see the factory method as being very nearly as tightly coupled as a constructor. I'm not entirely convinced that it's really a separate responsibility, but I'll have to think about it some more.